# proof of an identity for exponential function

Tags: combinatorics

I am asked to prove $e^{(Y \log(1 + Z))} = (1 + Z)^Y$ using the power series definitions for both $\log(Z)$ and $e^Z$.  Our hint is to find a formula for the nth derivative of the power series expansion of $e^{(Y \log(1 + Z))}$ with respect to Z and then use it to find the coefficient on $Z^n$.  I have found that the formula for the nth derivative is $$\frac{(Y)_n}{(1 + Z)^n}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\left[Y \log(1 + Z)\right]^n$$ where $(Y)_n$ is the falling factorial.  I am stuck from here though and cannot figure out how to use this to find the coefficient on $Z_n$.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be missing something...  $Y$ is an integer constant, right?  Why would differentiating w.r.t. $Z$ result in something like $(Y)_n$ falling factorial?

Comment: Y and Z are indeterminates.  It is entirely possible derivation of the nth derivative is incorrect.

Comment: What I mean is: $Y$ is a constant as far as differentiating w.r.t. $Z$ is concerned.  So yeah, your derivative might be incorrect.

Comment: So that derivative wasn’t wrong if you take the nth derivative with some factoring you will see this works but I’m still stumped at this point